# What should I do with "not awaited coroutine" warning?

Tags: python-3.x, coroutine

First I do apologize for posting code using a proprietary library similar to a subset of `asyncio`. Anyway the question is not related to that library and I'm sure it will be readable for everybody familiar with asynchronous Python.

I have a standard coroutine, e.g.:

```
async def tcoro():
    pass
```

that is used as a timeout handler. For that purpose it is wrapped into a `Task` object. Basically the `Task` keeps the coroutine alive by repeating `send` calls. The task is scheduled to be run when the operation times out:

```
timer = loop.call_later(Task(tcoro()).run, delay=timeout)
```

But when the operation succeeds, the pending timeout gets cancelled with:

```
timer.cancel()
```

which just sets a cancelled flag. Later, when the `delay` is over, the event loop will pop the `timer` object out of the queue and because it got cancelled in the meantime, it will be ignored. And that produces:

```
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'tcoro' was never awaited
```

My question is how am I supposed to react to this warning when there is no problem with program's functionality?

Should I ignore it? Should I suppress it somehow? Should I rewrite the code because it is badly designed?

The fix is very simple:

```
def timeout():
    Task(tcoro()).run()

timer = loop.call_later(timeout, delay=timeout)
```

But I'm not sure if the original code is broken.

Comment: You have to `await` the task.